# MP3 audio file splitting with Python

Tags: python, mp3, slice

I have mp3 files and i want to slice these into samples, by giving a start and end time to a library function.
Does anyone know which python library suits me to do this??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Mp3splt](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/home.php), This works fabulously :)

Example:

```
import os
os.system("mp3splt inputfile.mp3")
```

Comment: They provide library which you could wrap (e.g. using boost::python) instead of calling commands. Or do you use `ctypes`?

Comment: I used their commands, `import os` `os.system("mp3splt inputfile.mp3")` etc